# How to get query parameter name from ConstraintViolationException

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate-validator, javax.validation

I have a service method:

```
 @GetMapping(path = "/api/some/path", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> getWhatever(@RequestParam(value = "page-number", defaultValue = "0") @Min(0) Integer pageNumber, ...
```

If the caller of an API doesn't submit a proper value for `page-number` query parameter, `javax.ConstraintViolationexception` is being raised. The message of the exception would read smth like:

`getWhatever.pageNumber must be equal or greater than 0`

In the response body, I would like to have this message instead:

`page-number must be equal or greater than 0`

I want my message to have the name of a query parameter, not the name of the argument. IMHO, including the name of the argument is exposing the implementation details.

The problem is, I cannot find an object that is carrying query parameter name. Seems like the `ConstraintViolationException` doesn't have it.

I am running my app in spring-boot.

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S.: I have been to the other similar threads that claim to solve the problem, none of them actually do in reality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how I made it work in spring-boot 2.0.3:

I had to override and disable `ValidationAutoConfiguration` in spring-boot:

```
import org.springframework.boot.validation.MessageInterpolatorFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationPostProcessor;

import javax.validation.Validator;

@Configuration
public class ValidationConfiguration {
    public ValidationConfiguration() {
    }

    @Bean
    public static LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setParameterNameDiscoverer(new CustomParamNamesDiscoverer());
        MessageInterpolatorFactory interpolatorFactory = new MessageInterpolatorFactory();
        factoryBean.setMessageInterpolator(interpolatorFactory.getObject());
        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public static MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor(Environment environment, @Lazy Validator validator) {
        MethodValidationPostProcessor processor = new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
        boolean proxyTargetClass = (Boolean) environment.getProperty("spring.aop.proxy-target-class", Boolean.class, true);
        processor.setProxyTargetClass(proxyTargetClass);
        processor.setValidator(validator);
        return processor;
    }
}
```

`CustomParamNamesDiscoverer` sits in the same package and it is a pretty much a copy-paste of `DefaultParameterNameDiscoverer`, spring-boot's default implementation of param name discoverer:

```
import org.springframework.core.*;
import org.springframework.util.ClassUtils;

public class CustomParameterNameDiscoverer extends PrioritizedParameterNameDiscoverer {
    private static final boolean kotlinPresent = ClassUtils.isPresent("kotlin.Unit", CustomParameterNameDiscoverer.class.getClassLoader());

    public CustomParameterNameDiscoverer() {
        if (kotlinPresent) {
            this.addDiscoverer(new KotlinReflectionParameterNameDiscoverer());
        }

        this.addDiscoverer(new ReqParamNamesDiscoverer());
        this.addDiscoverer(new StandardReflectionParameterNameDiscoverer());
        this.addDiscoverer(new LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer());
    }
}
```

I wanted it to remain pretty much intact (you can see even kotlin checks in there) with the only addition:
I am adding an instance of `ReqParamNamesDiscoverer` to the linked lists of discoverers. Note that the order of addition does matter here.

Here is the source code:

```
import com.google.common.base.Strings;
import org.springframework.core.ParameterNameDiscoverer;
import org.springframework.lang.Nullable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Executable;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Parameter;

public class ReqParamNamesDiscoverer implements ParameterNameDiscoverer {

    public ReqParamNamesDiscoverer() {
    }

    @Override
    @Nullable
    public String[] getParameterNames(Method method) {
        return doGetParameterNames(method);
    }

    @Override
    @Nullable
    public String[] getParameterNames(Constructor<?> constructor) {
        return doGetParameterNames(constructor);
    }

    @Nullable
    private static String[] doGetParameterNames(Executable executable) {
        Parameter[] parameters = executable.getParameters();
        String[] parameterNames = new String[parameters.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < parameters.length; ++i) {
            Parameter param = parameters[i];
            if (!param.isNamePresent()) {
                return null;
            }
            String paramName = param.getName();
            if (param.isAnnotationPresent(RequestParam.class)) {
                RequestParam requestParamAnnotation = param.getAnnotation(RequestParam.class);
                if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(requestParamAnnotation.value())) {
                    paramName = requestParamAnnotation.value();
                }
            }
            parameterNames[i] = paramName;
        }
        return parameterNames;
    }
}
```

If parameter is annotated with `RequestParam` annotation, I am retrieving the `value` attribute and return it as a parameter name.

The next thing was disabling auto validation config, somehow, it doesn't work without it. This annotation does the trick though:
`@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {ValidationAutoConfiguration.class})`

Also, you need to have a custom handler for your `ConstraintValidationException` :

```
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
    public ErrorDTO handleConstraintViolationException(ConstraintViolationException ex) {
        Map<String, Collection<String>> errors = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        ex.getConstraintViolations().forEach(constraintViolation -> {
            String queryParamPath = constraintViolation.getPropertyPath().toString();
            log.debug("queryParamPath = {}", queryParamPath);
            String queryParam = queryParamPath.contains(".") ?
                    queryParamPath.substring(queryParamPath.indexOf(".") + 1) :
                    queryParamPath;
            String errorMessage = constraintViolation.getMessage();
            Collection<String> perQueryParamErrors = errors.getOrDefault(queryParam, new ArrayList<>());
            perQueryParamErrors.add(errorMessage);
            errors.put(queryParam, perQueryParamErrors);
        });
        return validationException(new ValidationException("queryParameter", errors));
    }
```

`ValidationException` stuff is my custom way of dealing with validation errors, in a nutshell, it produces an error DTO, which will be serialized into JSON with all the validation error messages.

Comment: Thank you Guillaume Smet and @Gunnar for your help, for guiding me in the right direction.

Comment: "queryParam" is not working with nested objects. I would suggest to replace  it with regex.   String queryParam = queryParamPath.replaceAll(".*\\.", "");

Comment: You could simplify your `ValidationConfiguration`. a) The `methodValidationPostProcessor` method is not required. If not defined, the default autoconfiguration kicks in. b) Yu can build on the default implementation of the validator autoconfiguration in the `validator` method. `var factoryBean = ValidationAutoConfiguration.defaultValidator(applicationContext); factoryBean.setParameterNameDiscoverer(new CustomParamNamesDiscoverer()); return factoryBean;`

Answer (score 1):

Add a custom message to `@Min` annotation like this

```
@Min(value=0, message="page-number must be equal or greater than {value}")
```

Comment: Yeah but I think that's exactly what he wants to avoid.

Comment: Yeah, it is a viable solution, but I have approx 50 service classes, each of them having a multitude of constraints. This would clutter the code base and may introduce an error. I want to automate it. Also, if someone changes the name of the param and forgets to update the message, there will be a disconnect.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, you cannot do it (well, except if you define a custom message for each annotation but I suppose that's not what you want).

Funnily enough, someone worked recently on something very similar: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/pull/1029 .

This work has been merged to the master branch but I haven't released a new 6.1 alpha containing this work yet. It's a matter of days.

That being said, we had properties in mind and now that you ask that, we should probably generalize that to more things, method parameters included.

Now that we have the general idea, it shouldn't be too much work to generalize it, I think.

I'll discuss this with the contributor and the rest of the team and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks for your input!

Comment: There already is the `ParameterNameProvider` contract which could be implemented to obtain the name from the `@RequestParam` annotation. There'd still be the method name in the message, though.

Comment: Could you please guide me a little or send me a sample implementation?

Comment: Method name in the message is fine, I can easily remove it by inspecting a string.

Comment: See [the spec](https://beanvalidation.org/2.0/spec/#constraintdeclarationvalidationprocess-methodlevelconstraints-parameterconstraints-namingparameters) for the actual contract and ways of registering your implementation. In a nutshell, you'd fetch that `@RequestParam` annotation from the parameters of validated methods using reflection and return the list of names. You might fall back to the default behaviour (actual parameter names) in case the annotation isn't present.

Comment: @Gunnar how do I register my implementation of `ParameterNameProvider` in the framework?

Comment: ```import javax.validation.Validation;
import javax.validation.Validator;
import javax.validation.ValidatorFactory;

@Configuration
public class ValidationConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Validator validator() {
        final ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.byDefaultProvider()
                .configure()
                .parameterNameProvider(new ReqParamNamesAwareProvider())
                .buildValidatorFactory();
        return validatorFactory.getValidator();
    }
}```

Comment: LGTM, this should work. You also could try to register it via _validation.xml_.

Comment: It didn't work, so I thought maybe I need to add ` @Primary` annotation to my bean and the app suddenly started failing: 
`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.validation.Validator' available: more than one 'primary' bean found among candidates: [defaultValidator, validator]`

I am wondering now about this `defaultValidator` where it comes from and how I can override its behavior.
My app is also using hibernate.

Comment: I did some more investigation and `defaultValidator` comes form `ValidationAutoConfiguration.class`. I had to disable it using annotation:
`@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {ValidationAutoConfiguration.class})`
I have copied the contents of it, so that spring-boot works as expected. The only thing I need to do is update that `ParameterNameProvider`, but the object that is being returned is `LocalValidatorFactoryBean`. This class doesn't have a notion of `ParameterNameProvider`, but instead using `ParameterNameDiscoverer`. Super confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think getting the name of the query parameter is possible but would like to be proven wrong if somebody knows a way.

As Dmitry Bogdanovich says, having a custom message is the easiest and only way I know how to do something close to what you need. If you say you don't want to clutter your code with these messages, you can just do this:

Add a ValidationMessages.properties file in your resources folder. Here you can just say:

```
page_number.min=page-number must be equal or greater than {value}
```

Now you can use the annotation and write:

```
@Min(value = 0, message = "{page_number.min}")
```

This way you have a single source to change anything about the message when needed.

Comment: Read the comments of the other answer

Comment: I did read those comments and I was simply giving you an easy way of having all those messages in one place where you could change the parameters name if your RequestParameter changed. As I understand it there isn't a way to do it your way right now and I thought this could be a workaround.

Comment: I think there is s way and once I prove it works, I’ll post my solution here