# To perform not empty validation on Controller request param but the response contains controller method name and request param name

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jackson

I want to perform not empty validation on Controller request param but the response contains controller method name and request param name.Generally this should be avoided.

Controller class:

```
@PutMapping("/{id}/trains")
@ApiOperation(value = "Associate train with ticket")
public String associateTrainsToTicket(
        @RequestBody @Size(min = 1, message = "{Trains request list should not be empty.}") Set<Long> tickets,
        @Valid @PathVariable(name = "id") Long id) 
{

}
```

Current Response :

```
{
    "success": false,
    "validationError": {
        "Code": "EC_1001",
        "Messages": [
            "associateTrainsToTicket.tickets: Trains request list should not be empty."
        ]
    }
}
```

Required Response:

```
{
    "success": false,
    "validationError": {
        "Code": "EC_1001",
        "Messages": [
            "Trains request list should not be empty."
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Answers at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56467824/how-to-get-query-parameter-name-from-constraintviolationexception) question has some pointers to the solution.

Comment: @Smile here the validation is working fine but the controller method and request body field name are attaching as key in the response message.I do not wan't to have that

Comment: Answer mentioned in the above comment also provides solution for exactly same problem